# Discrete random variable probability distribution

Tags: probability

Question: A discrete random variable X has the following probability distribution.

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}  \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{x}} &
 \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{0}} &
 \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{4}} &
 \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{6}}\\\hline P(X=x)                  
 & p_0   & p_1   & p_2 \\\hline
                                       \end{array}
Given that E (X)=4.1 and Var(X) = 4.99, find the values of $p_0$ , $p_1$ and $p_2$.

My attempt:
 E(X)= $0\times p_0 + 4\times p_1
+6\times p_1=4.1 $ 
how to proceed from here?

Comment: Correct, then you need to use $Var(X)+\mathbb{E}^2=\mathbb{E}[X^2]=0^2\times p_0+4^2\times p_1+6^2\times p_2$. It means that you have a system of two equations with two variables and you can conclude solving it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Similarly compute $EX^{2}$. Then use the fact that $4.99=var(X)=EX^{2}-(EX)^{2}$. Now you have two equations involving $p_0,p_1,p_2$.  Remember that $p_0+p_1+p_2=1$. Now you have to solve these three equations to find the values of $p_0,p_1$ and $p_2$.